# Can I run Robot tests with Appium Browserstack?

Tags: browserstack, saucelabs, perfecto, kobiton, headspin

Can I run tests written Robot Framework in Browserstack for automated testing?

If BrowserStack does not support it which framework supports it?

- Sauce labs
- Perfecto
- Kobiton
- Headspin

Also, I am wondering whether other frameworks support Robot with Appium or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Robot Framework with Appium on BrowserStack's Automate as well as for App Automate on real devices.

For reference and walkthrough guide, please refer to the documentation here:

1. https://github.com/nithyamn/bstack-robot-framework#automate
2. https://github.com/nithyamn/bs-robot-framework#app-automate

Hope this helps.

Regards,
BrowserStack Support

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robotframework with Sauce Labs, here are some code examples:

https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-python/tree/main/examples/robotframework